# NGINX keep URL at /location/some-path and serve /location/?

Tags: nginx, url, redirect, url-rewriting, nginx-reverse-proxy

Is this possible?

User enters **https://mywebsite.com/location/any-path**

Nginx runs **https://mywebsite.com/location/**

URL displays **https://mywebsite.com/location/any-path**

Is there a particular name for this type of action also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nginx redirection here -

```
location = /location/any-path {
   return 301 /location;
  }
```

Comment: This answer is not what I'm looking for. Here is why:<br>
1. it changes the URL to /location (instead of keeping /location/any-path)
2. It does not work with all/different values in "any-path" (so that different "any-path"s all serve "/location")

Answer (score 0):

You want to `proxy_pass` the request to another url and then `proxy_redirect` to alter the url displayed to the client.

Something like this:

```
location ~ /location/(.+) {
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    proxy_pass https://mywebsite.com/location/index.php;
    proxy_redirect /location/ /location/$1/;
}
```

Comment: the syntax is redirecting without the proxy_redirect URL altering? @miknik

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? Client to see the same url they entered?

Comment: its changing URL to /location/ instead of /location/some-path @miknik